# Shortcut for Back View (Ctrl 1) doesn't work

Tags: interface, customization, shortcut

This is really strange.

When I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>1</kbd> the view should switch to Back View, according to my preferences.

[image: Keyboard configuration for Ctrl 1 shortcut]

It's even listed correctly in the menu:

[image]

**It doesn't do anything.**

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>3</kbd> for Left View is working, and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>7</kbd> for Bottom View is also working.

I use Emulate Numpad as a standard always, even on machines where a numpad keyboard is available.

My OS is macOS Sierra. Blender version is 2.79.

The most bizarre thing is that it still doesn't work *even after I Load Factory Settings* (and re-enable Emulate Numpad). This makes me think it might not be my settings at all. (Possible bug?)

My <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and my <kbd>1</kbd> key are working just fine for all other uses, in Blender and in other apps.

It's really a hindrance when modeling. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Comment: Check if the operating system is using that same shortcut and re-map it or disable it... or get a proper keyboard with numpad or a usb numpad...

Comment: Thanks @cegaton. It certainly could be a system thing, although when I check in macOS System Preferences the only item I see using Ctrl 1 is a *disabled* shortcut for Mission Control. I do have a “proper” numpad keyboard on this machine, but I also use machines that don't, and I want consistency therefor I use Emulate Numpad as standard practice. I will keep searching for possible causes for macOS interfering, in case that is what is happening.

Comment: Have you tried it on other blender versions? Also, what happens when you remove your blender config files?

Comment: @Allosteric I  have verified that on another machine I use (MacBook Pro) with the same Blender 2.79 and the same macOS Sierra 10.12.6 there is no problem whatsoever. I have also verified that the problem does not originate with the settings, because I tried removing the config files, and even swapped them with those from the working system. The iMac continues to have the problem regardless of the config folder status.

Comment: Try some show-what-key-you-are-pressing software within and outside blender. As for within, Screencast addon should be useful. As for outside, googling it gives you a dosen of choices. If you still have problems outsode blender, you should consult a macOS community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The macOS Japanese text input implementation was interfering. By disabling it and using the [Google IME](https://www.google.co.jp/ime/) instead I was able to regain normal functionality of my Ctrl key.

Anyone wanting to know more can read [the question I posted on Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/315543/) that led to solving the mystery.

Answer (score -1):

Just using the blender in full screen mode enable ctrl+1 to be active.